# while loop is not running correctly

Tags: python

In my code for guessing game, even when the guess is 1, it returns that the guess is too high. Cant figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Aside, your last print line seems to be incomplete. I believe you want to show number of guesses but your `guessCounter` is actually a running list with the `guessNums` appended. So, add a `+ len(guessCounter)` at end of print statement. Also, it wouldn't be average but total.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you should not be using raw_input as this will get you a string and not an integer. Try using input

Please see this question for more details: [Python read input as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Comment: Important to note that raw_input is no longer available as of Python 3.0

Comment: i tried that too and it wont get rid of the issue which it always outputs guess is too high even when i input '1' and I'm running 2.7

Comment: I just ran the code with the change suggested: int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 100: ')); and also: print str(guessNum) + " is too low". The code worked fine

Comment: Make sure to change the raw_input in all 3 places

Comment: I tried the str(guessNum), now it only returns that it is too low instead of too high even when I tried 99

Comment: And i really appreciate your help =D

Comment: Are you sure you changed all the raw_inputs to inputs? It works fine for me when I change it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your `guessNum` is string. Need to make it to int when ever you expect a user to input an integer. For example:

```
guessNum = int(raw_input('Enter a number between 1 and 100: '))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jae\Desktop\Scripting\q1", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Jae\Desktop\Scripting\q1", line 12, in main
    print guessNum + " is too low"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @JeffCrackalack You cant add integers to strings. to do so, need to convert int to string or you string formating. Example of the first case: `str(guessNum) + " is too high, try again:"` and second: `"{} is too high, try again:".format(guessNum)`

Comment: can you please examine my comment to the answer(Chuckie) below. I really don't understand why its not printing correctly. Thank you so much